# Define a shared .cshtml file and render it on a sub-page in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have defined a very simple form on /Shared/Forms/_ContactForm.cshtml, let's say it's just a stack of labels like this (whole file):

```
@{
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Ipsum</li>
        <li>Dolor</li>
    </ul>
}
```

My objective is to reuse that form on my Contact.cshtml sub-page and at the foot of all my personal projects sub-pages

I'm editing my Contact.cshtml file and trying to use @RenderPage() in order to display my form, by using this (whole file):

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Contact";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<p>Contact with me!</p>

<body>
    @RenderPage("~/Shared/Forms/_ContactForm.cshtml")
</body>
```

But I get an error Error CS0103: Name 'RenderPage' doesn't exist in the current context

I have tried to change the whole Contact.cshtml file by starting it with  as suggested in that Microsoft guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/3-creating-a-consistent-look and starting it with the `<!DOCTYPE html>`. But if I do that I loose the tab section defined in my _Layout.cshtml and it is cumbersome to add all elements again manually. I'm sure I'm doing it bad since I have just started with ASP.NET Core MVC (my last experience was Xamarin, first time programming webapps...), so any advice or link would be very helpful for me.

EDIT: Also tried like suggested in comments

```
<body>
    <partial>
        @Html.RenderPartialAsync("~/Shared/Forms/_ContactForm.cshtml")
    </partial>
</body>
```

It compiles but just shows this as text:
[image: Running result]

Comment: RenderPage only work in WebPages, for MVC use Html.RenderPartial

Comment: @DA it raises a can't implicit convert void in object, and a warning asking for using <partial> tag or IHtmlHelper.RenderPartialAsync. I have tried with <partial> tag with no success, and RenderPartialAsync() and the combination of two advices, it compile but my page shows this as text: System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<body>
    <partial>
        @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/Forms/_ContactForm.cshtml")
    </partial>
</body>
```

Or use the `name` attribute of the `partial` tag directly:

```
<body>
    <partial name="~/Views/Shared/Forms/_ContactForm.cshtml" />
</body>
```

Please note its path.

Test Result:

[image]

For more detail, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-7.0#partial-tag-helper).

Comment: You are right, the path was the problem since I moved the file and forget to change the path. It works with your purposed solutions and with the others mentiones on my EDIT, you all have been very helpful, thanks a lot